# Define Range by Header VBA

Tags: vba, excel, columnheader

I have a range definition in VBA that looks like this:

```
Sheet5.Range(Range("K2"), Sheet5.Range("K2").End(xlDown))
```

This works but if the layout of my report ever changes, it will not work.  I was wondering if it was possible to define the range based on the header in the first row of the column? Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below example searches for the header based on the name. In the example, it colors the entire column `Red` based on match, but you can change that. The variables should be easy to follow, but please let me know of questions.

```
Sub Color_Range_Based_On_Header()
    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim rngHdrFound As Range

    Const ROW_HEADERS As Integer = 1
    Const HEADER_NAME As String = "Location"

    Set rngHeaders = Intersect(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange, Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(ROW_HEADERS))
    Set rngHdrFound = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME)

    If rngHdrFound Is Nothing Then
        'Do whatever you want if the header is missing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Range(rngHdrFound, rngHdrFound.End(xlDown)).Interior.Color = vbRed

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is the HEADER_NAME variable set to "Location"?

Comment: Sorry, that is just a text name. In my case, my code searches for the header with text 'Location'. That should be changed to whatever your header actually contains, e.g. ("Date", "Name", "Department"). Basically, whatever text you currently have in Cell K1.

Comment: Good to hear. I used those Constant at the top of my code so that I can change that easily whenever necessary

Comment: How would I offset the range by 1 cell so that it doesn't include the header?

Comment: In the last line of the code I posted (before the `End Sub` line), you change it to: `Range(rngHdrFound.Offset(1), rngHdrFound.End ...`

Comment: Ok. Also, I am getting a subscript out of range error on this line:

`Set rngHeaders = Intersect(Worksheets(sheetName).UsedRange, Worksheets(sheetName).Rows(ROW_HEADERS))`

Comment: How did you define `sheetName`? Is it a string variable? If so, the code should work fine, presuming the `sheetName` has been appropriately set to the sheet name. (Not the worksheet names are case sensitive).

Answer (score 1):

You can name a range with any kind of name you would like.  In the upper left hand corner you can see the id of the selected range.  If you type a name in there like "Header_Cell" you can change your code to:

```
Sheet5.Range(Range("Header_Cell"), Sheet5.Range("Header_Cell").End(xlDown))
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that but if the layout of my report changes the ranges will shift and this will not work.

Comment: Cute idea to *Name* the header cell, the code will still work if columns are added/deleted **(+1)**

Comment: Oh I see now. Do I just rename it near the formula bar?